# Undesired results from calculating powers of 2 [C++]

Tags: c++, debugging, loops, vector

Okay, I'm done banging my head against my desk.  I'm trying to compute huge powers of 2 [beyond what's capable of being held in the uint64_t data type] by holding digits in a vector of 'char's.  Here is my program, followed by my actual outputs:

```
/*
This program doubles a very large number by using a vector of char types
Usage: program.exe [number]
Output will be 2^[number]
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<char> BigNum;
    BigNum.push_back('2');
    int carry=0, digit;
    int power=atoi(argv[1]);
    power-=1;
    for(int x=0;x<power;x++)                            //Example: going from 16 to 32.  x==4
    {
        for(int y=BigNum.size()-1;y>=0;y--)             //Go from BigNum[1] to BigNum[0] ('6' then '1')
        {
            digit=atoi(&BigNum[y]);                     //digit = 6, then digit=1
            BigNum[y]=(char)(((digit*2+carry)%10)+48);  //BigNum[1]=(char)(6*2+0)%10+48 = '2' in char
                                                        //BigNum[0]=(char)(1*2+1)%10+48 = '3' in char
            carry=digit*2/10;                           //carry=1, then 0
        }
        if(carry==1)                                    //does not execute.  BigNum=={'3','2'}
        {
            BigNum.push_back('0');
            for(int y=BigNum.size()-1;y>0;y--)
            {
                BigNum[y]=BigNum[y-1];
            }
            BigNum[0]='1';
            carry=0;
        }
    }
    for(int x=0;x<BigNum.size();x++) cout<<BigNum[x];
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ program.cpp -o program
```

So here are my results when I run the program:

```
C:\MyApps\program 2
4
C:\MyApps\program 3
8
C:\MyApps\program 4
16
```

Okay, looks good so far... even my "if(carry==1)" section, where I push a number to the FRONT of the vector works, since we "carried the 1" to get into double digits.  Let's continue:

```
C:\MyApps\program 5
52
```

What?

```
C:\MyApps\program 6
26
```

What what?

```
C:\MyApps\program 654
84
C:\MyApps\program 654444
00
```

It never gets to triple digits... and what the heck is going on?

Comment: Homework? Please tag so.

Comment: This is not homework... I'm actually doing it for fun as part of the Project Euler series [projecteuler.net], Problem 16 to be precise.  And I don't know how to use a debugger.  :/  Would it help here?

Comment: Stepping through this might be the easiest way to figure this out.  Printing out each variable and doing a manual trace will help as well then the issue will probably jump out at you.

Comment: @sean, I did just that in my comments in the code.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Like @sean said, put some cout's in there and trace it down. It's too hard for us to figure it out without an example that exhibits the problem exactly. Like, "cout << digit" and "cout << BigNum[0].. BigNum[1]", etc.

Comment: I don't understand why downvotes apply here. He asked a perfectly legitimate question, and it was well formatted. The title could use some work, but instead of downvoting, edit it!

Comment: Oh no, my first downvote!  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying `atoi` to something that isn't a null-terminated string. In practice, it may well look in memory like a null-terminated string, but not the one you actually want it to look like.

The cleanest way to fix this is probably to store actual digit values 0..9 rather than ASCII '0'..'9' in your vector. You'll find that the code is nicer that way too.

Comment: I think you're right.  I did as the others suggested in comments to the original post, and right when I do "digit=atoi(&BigNum[y]);" to a digit of a non-1-digit number, it throws me a weird number.

Comment: That was it!  I changed to using vector<int> and am getting the correct results now.  Thanks!